# Double Vpn Virtual Box and Host Os. Virt vpn reaching outside net or not?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, vpn

I am using a vpn in my host Os and a vpn in my virtualbox. Both are running ok. Inside virtual box I see the vpn inside virtualbox is running ok. Outside of virtualbox the vpn for my Os works fine too.
If I close my virtualbox vpn the virtualbox connects inmediatly to my host vpn.

Here now its the question... I see through wireshark all websites I browse through virtualbox even though virtualbox is connected to vpn.

So...

**Does this mean virtualbox connections (the vpn of virtualbox) does reach the open internet without being forwarded to my host vpn?**

**Is there any way I could find if the virtualbox vpn ip is leaking to the outside (normal isp ip instead of touching first the host Os vpn?**

**Finally, why would wireshark be able to find info regarding all the websites I browse inside the virtual machine, if this one is using a vpn and therefore they should be encripted?**

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your virtual machine's network is configured.  If your virtual machine is set to bridged mode, than it has its own IP and connection.  Disabling its VPN means traffic will not be encrypted.  If the virtual machine is in NAT mode, it uses the host machine's IP and will remain encrypted by that IP, as long as its VPN is active.

As for why Wireshark can see the websites you visit is due to the fact DNS requests are not encrypted, just the traffic between the end points of the VPN.

Comment: So do you mean therefore if virtual machines network is configured as NAT (currently that is my case), my virtualbox is really forwarding one connnection through another (my Os vpn does allow this kind of thing)? Thank you for the answer, you are right DNS requests are the ones not encrypted as I have check out right now.

Comment: @Jimmy that is correct.